# How to make notification appear at exact hours. For example at 12 : 00, 13 : 00, 14 : 00, 15 : 00 and so on

Tags: java, android, kotlin, push-notification, android-notifications

**Problem** - Cannot make notification appear every hour (12 : 00, 13 : 00, 14 : 00 and so on), it has to be at exact hours (o'clock)(give me some advice how I can describe it well) you got the point, I hope)

**So I have tried**

**Application class**

```
import android.app.Application
import androidx.hilt.work.HiltWorkerFactory
import androidx.work.Configuration
import com.io.notification.WorkInTime
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltAndroidApp
class Application : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

    @Inject
    lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration =
        Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        WorkInTime().runEveryHour(1, 15,  this.applicationContext)
//        WorkInTime().runEveryDay(1, applicationContext)
    }
}
```

**Class that does scheduling**

```
class WorkInTime {

     fun runEveryDay(hourOfTheDay: Int, context: Context) {

        val repeatInterval = 1 // In days
        val flexTime: Long = calculateFlex(hourOfTheDay, repeatInterval)

        schedule(repeatInterval, flexTime, context, TimeUnit.DAYS)
    }

    fun runEveryHour(repeatInterval: Int, flexTime: Long, context: Context){
        schedule(repeatInterval, flexTime, context, TimeUnit.HOURS)
    }

    private fun schedule(repeatInterval: Int, flexTime: Long, context: Context, timeUnit: TimeUnit) {
        val myConstraints: Constraints = Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(false)
            .build()

        val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<NotifyWork>(
            repeatInterval.toLong(), timeUnit,
            flexTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
        )
            .setConstraints(myConstraints)
            .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            "YOUR_NICE_WORK_TAG",
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
            workRequest
        )
    }
}
```

**Calculate flex extension**

```
fun calculateFlex(hourOfTheDay: Int, periodInDays: Int): Long {

    val cal1 = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal1[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = hourOfTheDay
    cal1[Calendar.MINUTE] = 0
    cal1[Calendar.SECOND] = 0

    // Initialize a calendar with now.
    val cal2 = Calendar.getInstance()
    if (cal2.timeInMillis < cal1.timeInMillis) {
        // Add the worker periodicity.
        cal2.timeInMillis = cal2.timeInMillis + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(periodInDays.toLong())
    }
    val delta = cal2.timeInMillis - cal1.timeInMillis
    return if (delta > PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_FLEX_MILLIS) delta else PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_FLEX_MILLIS
}
```

**My Worker class**

```
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
import android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
import android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
import android.graphics.Color.RED
import android.media.AudioAttributes
import android.media.AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION
import android.media.AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE
import android.media.RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION
import android.media.RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri
import android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O
import android.widget.RemoteViews
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX
import androidx.work.CoroutineWorker
import androidx.work.ListenableWorker.Result.success
import androidx.work.Worker
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters

class NotifyWork(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params) {

    override  fun doWork(): Result {
        val id = inputData.getLong(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0).toInt()
        sendNotification(id)
        return success()
    }

    private fun sendNotification(id: Int) {
        val intent = Intent(
            applicationContext,
            Class.forName("com.stenleone.clenner.ui.activity.MainActivity")
        )
        intent.flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, id)

        val notificationManager =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val notificationLayoutExpanded =
            RemoteViews(applicationContext.packageName, R.layout.layout_notification)

        val bitmap = applicationContext.vectorToBitmap(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
        val pendingIntent = getActivity(applicationContext, 0, intent, 0)

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)
            .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setCustomContentView(notificationLayoutExpanded)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        notification.priority = PRIORITY_MAX

        if (SDK_INT >= O) {
            notification.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)

            val ringtoneManager = getDefaultUri(TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
            val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
                .setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION).build()

            val channel =
                NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL, NOTIFICATION_NAME, IMPORTANCE_HIGH)

            channel.enableLights(true)
            channel.lightColor = RED
            channel.enableVibration(true)
            channel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
            channel.setSound(ringtoneManager, audioAttributes)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        notificationManager.notify(id, notification.build())
    }

    companion object {
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = "appName_notification_id"
        const val NOTIFICATION_NAME = "appName"
        const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL = "appName_channel_01"
        const val NOTIFICATION_WORK = "appName_notification_work"
    }
}
```

**SO the First problem is** - For example:  if I open the app at 13 : 20, it will show the notification at 14 : 20, but I need to make notification appear at 14 : 00

**The Second problem is**  - For example: If I open the app at 13 : 20 it will schedule notification appear at 14 : 20 (after an hour), and if I kill the app and open it again  let's say at 13 : 50 it will re-schedule notification to  appear at 14 : 50,

So the previous scheduling, is re-scheduled kinda overwritten, I think if we can solve the first problem the second problem will be solved as well

**The Third Problem is**  - Need to do: When the notification appears, make the rest of the display blackish

[Check it out, how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBMYr.png)

[Check it out, my case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQpaV.jpg)

Comment: `WorkManager` is unsuitable for work that has to happen at particular times. Try `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Can AlarmManager trigger High Priority Notification when app is in killed state? When let's say I have removed the app from recent opened apps by swiping top or right or left ?

Comment: "When let's say I have removed the app from recent opened apps by swiping top or right or left ?" -- the exact behavior of such user actions depends on device model. `AlarmManager` and `WorkManager` should behave the same, though, for any given model.